# cant change label and buttons values

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a simple quiz-game application using JavaFx. I want set text on label and buttons with data from a list and table.

I created three class: Main, Controller and Quiz.fxml. I have problem with communication classes and method. 
In 'Main.java' I created object "Controller controller = new Controller()" and I call method "controller.setText" from 'Controller.java' class.

Now, I have a few options:

-if declate list(ArrayList questions) and tab(String[][] answers) in constuctor 'public Controller(){}' app doesnt work, I get error in this line "  "

-if declare everything in 'Text()' method(list, tab and setting text on label) application run but values buttons and label are not changed

-if I declare list and tab in 'setData()', and next I want to change the buttons and label value from 'Text()' method, I cant see the list and I have to declare the same list 'questions' in 'Text()'

```
public class Main extends Application {



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Controller/Quiz.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,400)
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    controller.Text();}
```

Controller class:

```
public class Controller  {

@FXML private Label questionLabel;
@FXML private RadioButton answer_btn1;
@FXML private RadioButton answer_btn2;
@FXML private RadioButton answer_btn3;
@FXML private RadioButton answer_btn4;
@FXML private Button nextBtn;



public void Text() {
    List <String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();

    questions.add("pytanie1");
    questions.add("pytanie2");
    questions.add("pytanie3");
    questions.add("pytanie4");
    questions.add("pytanie5");
    questions.add("pytanie6");
    questions.add("pytanie7");
    questions.add("pytanie8");
    questions.add("pytanie9");
    questions.add("pytanie10");

    String[][] answers = new String[1][4];
    answers[1][1] = "a) odp";
    answers[1][2] = "b) odp";
    answers[1][3] = "c) odp";
    answers[1][4] = "d) odp";


    questionLabel.setText("");

    questionLabel.setText(questionLabel.getText()+answers[1][1]);
    answer_btn1.setText("aaa");
}
```

What do I have to do to change name buttons and label?

Comment: Why are you doing `Controller controller = new Controller();
    controller.Text();`? I don't see its purpose. If you need to initialize the `Controller` use the `Controller's` `@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {//your code here!}` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems with your code.

1. Array index starts at zero and if necessary should end at arrayLength - 1. Your code: `answers[1][1] = "a) odp"; ... answers[1][4] = "d) odp";`. What it should be: `answers[0][0] = "a) odp"; ... answers[0][3] = "d) odp";`
2. Initialzing the Controller should be done in the Controller's initialize method.

The sample code below:

**Main:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication226 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Controller/Quiz.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Label questionLabel;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton answer_btn1;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton answer_btn2;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton answer_btn3;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton answer_btn4;
    @FXML
    private Button nextBtn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
        List<String> questions = new ArrayList();

        questions.add("pytanie1");
        questions.add("pytanie2");
        questions.add("pytanie3");
        questions.add("pytanie4");
        questions.add("pytanie5");
        questions.add("pytanie6");
        questions.add("pytanie7");
        questions.add("pytanie8");
        questions.add("pytanie9");
        questions.add("pytanie10");

        String[][] answers = new String[1][4];
        answers[0][0] = "a) odp";
        answers[0][1] = "b) odp";
        answers[0][2] = "c) odp";
        answers[0][3] = "d) odp";

        questionLabel.setText("");

        questionLabel.setText(questionLabel.getText() + answers[0][0]);
        answer_btn1.setText("aaa");
    }

}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication226.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="nextBtn" layoutX="118.0" layoutY="161.0" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="questionLabel" layoutX="124.0" layoutY="36.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="answer_btn1" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="92.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="answer_btn2" layoutX="193.0" layoutY="92.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="answer_btn3" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="answer_btn4" layoutX="183.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I am assuming your project structure looks like the following from your code. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. At the begining I created three package: Controller(inside Controller.java), View(inside Quiz.fxml) and Model(inside Main.java). When I opened Quiz.fxml with Scene Builder I wanted setting Controller class on my AnchorPane but there was no choice from the list(other package). Only when I moved Quiz.fxml to package Controller, I managed to set controll class. What is the way to set *.fxml controller from the another package?

Comment: Ask a new question and show your project structure. I have a guess, but that's all it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are instantiating a new controller which is not bound to the view.

You get the controller from the loader like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Controller/Quiz.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
Controller controller = loader.getController();
```

This way everything will be wired up properly.

Comment: ok, I changed `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Controller/Quiz.fxml"));` on your example. Application is running, but still values buttons are not changed. If I close app windows, in console appears error: "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException " and focus on lines: `controller.Text();` and `answers[1][1] = "a) odp";`